# Structured text PLC programming. Flash a light on and off

Tags: timer, plc

I am writing a program using automation software for controlling an oil tank.

I have several alarm signals, if any of these signals become true this triggers an alarm flag. This Alarm flag then needs to light up a warning lamp. Up to this stage I am fine, however I am trying to make the lamp flash on and off.

I know I have to use timers and so far have implemented that turns the lamp on for 2s and then off for 2s but I don't know how to loop this so it continues to do so until a reset button is pressed.

This is my code so far;

```
PROGRAM _CYCLIC

    Warning_Lamp;

    TON_Warning(IN := Alarm_Active_Flag_1 , PT := T#2s );

    IF(TON_Warning.Q = TRUE)THEN

        Warning_Lamp := TRUE;

    END_IF


    TON_Warning_2(IN := TON_Warning.Q , PT := T#2s );

    IF(TON_Warning_2.Q = TRUE)THEN

        Warning_Lamp := FALSE;

    END_IF



END_PROGRAM
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the platform of PLC or syntax and conventions of the STL for that PLC I can't give you the most efficient example, but here's a little pseudo-code that should get the point across

```
// Set a Bit to indicate an alarm was triggered
IF(Alarm_State := TRUE) THEN
    Wait_For_Reset = TRUE;
END_IF

// Condition your code off the state of that bit rather than your alarm bit
IF(Wait_For_Reset := TRUE) THEN
    //YOUR CODE HERE

END_IF

//Reset the bit that controls your code loop when the user presses Reset
IF(Reset_Pressed := TRUE) THEN
    Wait_For_Reset = FALSE:
END_IF
```

I would avoid DO/WHILE loops unless this is the only job this PLC has, because with most platforms I've encountered, a DO/WHILE loop interrupts the normal scan of the PLC until the loop completes.

Now obviously this doesn't do anything to the Actual Alarm bit, only what your code does if it's HIGH, and if the alarm condition still exists then it will just set again and continue processing your code. If you want to prevent that from happening, it would be best to use an Rising Edge Input from Alarm_State to set the Wait_For_Reset bit. That way it only sets once for each LO/HIGH transition of the Alarm_State. Every PLC I've encountered has some version of Rising Edge Bit. If you want to do that manually in code then you could do something like this:

```
IF(Alarm_State := TRUE AND WFR_ONS := FALSE) THEN
    Wait_For_Reset := TRUE;
    WFR_ONS := TRUE; //One Shot
END_IF

IF(Alarm_State := FALSE) THEN
    WFR_ONS := FALSE;
END_IF
```

The rest would remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

count := count +1;

IF count > 2000 THEN
count:=0;

END_IF

IF count>500 THEN

Lamp:TRUE;

ELSE
   lamp:=FALSE;

END_IF

// for 2 seconds (cycle time = 1ms*2000)